# R customized function using if() does not work as designed

Tags: r, function, debugging

reproducible dataset

```
set.seed(2023)
pid <- 1:30
y1 <- rnorm(30, 10, 10)
y2 <- rnorm(30, 10, 10)
x1 <- rnorm(30, 5, 2)
x2 <- rnorm(30, 5, 2)
x3 <- rnorm(30, 300, 3)

data <- data.frame(pid, y1, y2, x1, x2, x3)
```

```
apple<-function(data=data,
         first,
         second,
         Third=NULL){
  require(tidyverse)
if(!is.null(Third)){
  data<-data %>%
    mutate(new=first+second+Third)
  
if(is.null(Third)){
  
  data <- data %>%
    mutate(new=first-second)
}
}
  
  return(data)
}
```

However, it never works

```
results<-apple(data=data, first=x1, second=x2, Third=NULL)
```

it never makes 'new' column in data

I want to make a function that makes 'new' new column in dataset.
what contains in new column depends on Third argument in the function

But if i see the results dataframe, it does not have 'new' column which means that this function did not work as designed.

Comment: Why are you asking two times the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75904913/6574038)?

Comment: typo `tydiverse`!

Comment: The second `if` statement is nested inside the first. See how there is no curly bracket after the first `mutate()`? As a result, if `Third = NULL`, none of the code inside the function gets run, and unchanged data is returned. And yes, typo in the name of the library.

Comment: it is similar but turned out that these two functions have different indepedent problems.

Comment: Did you consider above upvoted comment? It answers your question

Comment: @Waldi yep, I appreciate it but I am not authorized to upvote comment yet.  so I could not do anything